# Why the answer will be "GOOD"?

Tags: java, class, object, interface

Following is the code I tried to run, the output was `Good`. So, we can use a variable of interface implemented by a class?

```
interface IDummyInterface {
    public String TYPE = "Good";
}

class Test implements IDummyInterface {

}

public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Test.TYPE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any class that implements an interface, and any class that extends a class that implements that interface, inherits all of that interfaces variables. No matter how you declare the variables in the interface, all interface variables are `public static final`, which is why you can access them with just the class name and not an instance of the class.

Comment: That's why you can omit the `public` in the interface declaration, less verbose.

Answer (score 2):

`Test` implements `IDummyInterface`.so all variables of `IDummyInterface` are inherited

Answer (score 2):

The variable is actually `static final`. And since it is `static`, it follows the same rules as all static variables declared in classes, which are accessible through any other class that inherit from it. In that regard interfaces behave like classes.

```
class StaticTestParent { public static final int VALUE = 1; }
class StaticTestChild extends StaticTestParent { }

static {
  System.out.println(StaticTestChild.VALUE);
}
```